# Why IsCallback doesn't work in Master page?

Tags: c#, callback, master-pages

I am using a Master page and I have to perform a function on initial load. I'm using Ajax and devExpress controls so I have to check !IsPostback and !IsCallback. When I try to use IsCallback the intelisense doesn't work and if I write it anyway I get an error message "The name IsCallback doesn't exist in the current context". However with Page.IsCallback intelisense works and no error message is given.

Is there an explenation for this? Is there a problem with checking callbacks in master pages?

Comment: interesting ... even I didn't notice this previously

Answer (score 2):

Actual explanation is simple enough: `MasterPage` class itself [defines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage_properties.aspx) only `IsPostback`, and does not define `IsCallback`. `Page` class on the other hand [has both](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_properties.aspx) these properties. That is why intellisense gave you nothing in for sole `IsCallback`.

I believe the reason behind this is that master pages are not designed to differentiate between types of requests - this job is left for pages. In any way callback is just a special type of postback. In other words `IsCallback` is true only when `IsPostback` is true, so `IsPostback` should suffice for your need.

Comment: From my experience I think I've seen IsPostback being false and IsCallback is true. I've seen code often if(!IsPostBack && !IsCallback) to be sure that this is the first page load.

Comment: @DovMiller, can you share info about the cases when `IsPostback` is false while `IsCallback` is true? Callback framework in ASP.NET is just an implementation of Ajax requests server-side handling, while postback is a term indicating whether the page was requested after the first load. Since ajax call is a request either way, callback is nothing more than a special form of postback.

Comment: I have found that IsCallback is not recognized in user controls either however Page.IsCallback is.